# Big performance issues/crashing using backbone on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, mobile, backbone.js

we have built our service dailymus.es to be mobile friendly, but we are hitting on a range of performance issues when accessing it on the mobile phone.

Specifically, it crashes after a few "pages" and when we have a lot of content on the page.

I am suspecting that we have too many event handlers and/or memory leaks. What methods do you use to eliminate these problems with Backbone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you test your site using **Google Chrome's Developers Console**. Use the **Profile** tab to examine the state of the heap.

Most leaks of backbone models/views are due to not detaching the DOM events from views and the binding (on) events from models.

Make sure to override the *remove* method of your backbone view and make sure you .off() from everything you set to .on(). Don't forget to call remove on sub-views.

To find leaks:

1. Take a snapshot
2. Run your code to create a view and then remove it
3. Take another snapshot
4. Compare the snapshots to find the new objects created who weren't released.

[More about the Google Chrome Heap Profiler](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling)

Comment: hey tal, thanks a lot for your comment! i am currently trying out google heap profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone wastes a lot of memory which is the hardest thing for mobile. There's a lot of techniques for object pooling on the DOM elements, updating elements instead of recreating templates, limit loading images until the last minute, holding any updates until right before the paint cycle.

Mobile web can be performant if the memory is managed properly. PrefView is a good example and can get 50FPS on long scroll list on an iPad mini. https://github.com/puppybits/BackboneJS-PerfView

Comment: 'Backbone wastes a lot of memory which is the hardest thing for mobile'. That statement is most certainly false. Leaks tend to happen because views are not managed properly and events are not properly disposed. This is definitely not an issue with the library itself.

Comment: By wasting a lot of memory isn't not about leaks. Leaks are not the main issue with mobile web development. In backbone the main pattern is to re-render (meaning delete elements off the DOM and recreate the elements). This happens every time a model changes. The browser is what uses most of the memory and CPU time and Backbone doesn't help you use the browser efficiently. You should always use performance tools to find the largest issues first. poor DOM usage, any images, network call, CSS, unneeded reflow cycle, poor GPU texture usage all will suck down much more memory and CPU then leaks.

Comment: If you look at the timeline events for dailymus.es in chrome dev tools when going to the homepage you'll see the biggest issues. 4 seconds to download the popular.json, about 200 compositeLayers/paint cycles (while it's doing nothing) and about 400 Parse HTML calls. Caching the backbone template, having less templates, reusing (instead of destroying and recreating) DOM elements and not rendering more HTML than can fit on the screen (object pooling) will all get the performance much better.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I agree, but this has nothing to do with the library. If you are re-rendering large parts of the DOM, then you need to break down your template into smaller parts. Backbone gives you freedom for your own implementation. It is that freedom that leads to problems on desktop and mobile, and NOT the library itself.

Comment: Right. It's probably more accurate to say the browser is built on a static page model. All web app frameworks go around this model by changing content. Backbone doesn't do anything to optimize the browser and that optimization is more important on mobile devices.